# Combine allMatch, noneMatch and anyMatch on a single stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to have the following logic: (i know it doesn't work because it consumes the stream more than once). but i am not sure how to achieve it.

```
Stream<ByteBuffer> buffers = super.getBuffers().stream();
if (buffers.allMatch(b -> b.position() > 0)) {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.FULLY_SENT;
} else if (buffers.noneMatch(b -> b.position() > 0)) {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.WAS_NOT_SENT;
} else {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.PARTIALLY_SENT;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What type has the result of `super.getBuffers()`?

Comment: It is List<ByteBuffer>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the result of `super.getBuffers()` is `List<ByteBuffer>`, you can iterate over it twice.

```
List<ByteBuffer> buffers = super.getBuffers();
if (buffers.stream().allMatch(b -> b.position() > 0)) {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.FULLY_SENT;
} else if (buffers.stream().noneMatch(b -> b.position() > 0)) {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.WAS_NOT_SENT;
} else {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.PARTIALLY_SENT;
}
```

Note that this still doesn’t need iterating over all elements in all cases. `allMatch` returns as soon as it encounters a non-matching element, `noneMatch` returns as soon as it encounters a matching element. So in the `PARTIALLY_SENT` case, it is possible that it got the conclusion without looking at all elements.

An alternative is

```
List<ByteBuffer> buffers = super.getBuffers();
if(buffers.isEmpty()) return OutgoingMessageStatus.FULLY_SENT;
Predicate<ByteBuffer> p = b -> b.position() > 0;
boolean sent = p.test(buffers.get(0));
if(!sent) p = p.negate();
return buffers.stream().skip(1).allMatch(p)? sent?
    OutgoingMessageStatus.FULLY_SENT:
    OutgoingMessageStatus.WAS_NOT_SENT:
    OutgoingMessageStatus.PARTIALLY_SENT;
}
```

The status of the first element determines which condition we have to check. As soon as there is a contradicting element, `allMatch` returns immediately and we have a `PARTIALLY_SENT` situation. Otherwise, all elements match like the first which implies either “all sent” or “none sent”.

The pre-check for an empty list produces the same behavior as the original code and ensures that `get(0)` never breaks.

---

If you really have a Stream instead of a source that you can iterate multiple times, there is no simple short-cutting solutions, as that would require a stateful predicate. There are, however, simple solutions processing all elements.

```
Map<Boolean,Long> result=getBuffers().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(b -> b.position() > 0, Collectors.counting()));
return
    result.getOrDefault(false, 0L)==0?
        OutgoingMessageStatus.FULLY_SENT:
    result.getOrDefault(true, 0L)==0?
        OutgoingMessageStatus.WAS_NOT_SENT:
        OutgoingMessageStatus.PARTIALLY_SENT;
```

or

```
return super.getBuffers().stream()
    .map(b -> b.position() > 0?
              OutgoingMessageStatus.FULLY_SENT: OutgoingMessageStatus.WAS_NOT_SENT)
    .reduce((a,b) -> a==b? a: OutgoingMessageStatus.PARTIALLY_SENT)
    .orElse(OutgoingMessageStatus.FULLY_SENT);
```

Comment: why is iterating twice is more efficient than the other suggested solutions? not sure i got it.

Comment: As explained in [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036522/combine-allmatch-nonematch-and-anymatch-on-a-single-stream/41036977#comment69281575_41036598), `allMatch` stops at the first non-matching element, `noneMatch` stops at the first matching element. So one of these two operations will stop right at the first element. The second still might also stop earlier, which is the case in the `PARTIALLY_SENT` scenario. This is also the case for my second, optimized, solution, which only reduces the number of checks by one. There is no solution performing lesser checks possible.

Comment: @Holger the last piece of code is absolutely sick! +1

Comment: Well detailed and few options, that's a very good answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Collectors.partitioningBy` always seems to produce a map with entries for both true and false, so the `getOrDefault` calls could be simplified. This isn't specified, though. Perhaps it should be.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: I know that. But since this isn’t explicitly specified, I decided to use `getOrDefault` here, which doesn’t hurt. By the way, [the special map returned by `partitioningBy`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#1540) *should* override some of the typical `Map` operations. Currently, it only implements `entrySet()` which makes even a simple `get` (with a `Boolean`) a surprisingly expensive operation, especially considering that a *new* entry set is instantiated every time, even for a simple `size()` call.

Comment: Yes, I was just looking at Collectors$Partition, and I noticed the missing overrides as well. Looks like some optimizations can be applied here. The internal implementation relies on both entries being present, and it simplifies things, so perhaps this should be brought into the specification as well.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: I would appreciate that.

Comment: @Holger Spec change is covered by [JDK-8170943](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170943), integrated in JDK 9 build 150 (posted 2016-12-22). Optimizations are covered by [JDK-8170945](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170945). Not sure when it'll be fixed, but it will be worked on at some point.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: regarding JDK-8170945, `containsKey` has `Object` parameter type, so it has to be `public boolean containsKey(Object key) { return key instanceof Boolean; }`. Further, I’d also vote for `@Override public void forEach(BiConsumer<? super Boolean, ? super V> c) { c.accept(Boolean.FALSE, forFalse); c.accept(Boolean.TRUE,  forTrue); }` to unleash the internal iteration benefit and well, if we are in a good mood, it wouldn’t hurt to also have `@Override public boolean containsValue(Object value) { return Objects.equals(forTrue, value) || Objects.equals(forFalse, value); }`…

Comment: @Holger D'oh, of course those methods aren't generic! Also, thanks for your additional suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `filter()`, and then count the number of elements that pass it :

```
Stream<ByteBuffer> buffers = super.getBuffers().stream();
int matches = buffers.filter(b -> b.position() > 0).count();
if (matches == super.getBuffers().size()) {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.FULLY_SENT;
} else if (matches == 0) {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.WAS_NOT_SENT;
} else {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.PARTIALLY_SENT;
}
```

This assumes that the data source of the `Stream` (`super.getBuffers()`) has a `size()` method. If it doesn't, you can count the total number of `ByteBuffer`s using an additional variable (less elegant, I know) :

```
int[] total = {0};
int matches = buffers.filter(b -> {total[0]++; return b.position() > 0;}).count();
if (matches == total[0]) {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.FULLY_SENT;
} else if (matches == 0) {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.WAS_NOT_SENT;
} else {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.PARTIALLY_SENT;
}
```

The disadvantage of that approach is that it doesn't fail fast when when only some of the elements pass the filter (i.e. output should be `OutgoingMessageStatus.PARTIALLY_SENT`). Perhaps you can use some `reduce` operation that returns one of the three possible outputs and only processes as many elements as necessary.

Comment: @Holger That's true. `allMatch()` requires full iteration only when it returns true.

Comment: Note that [iterating twice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41036977/2711488) is the most efficient way. Since the first element can be only either, matching or non-matching, either of `allMatch` or `nonMatch` will return immediately after checking the first element. The other check, if needed, will be short-circuiting. So it has at most *n* + 1 checks, but might have less. I have also provided a short-circuiting solution with at most *n* checks. Since your solutions requires the presence of a `size()` method, it also relies on `super.getBuffers()` returning a Collection.

Comment: @Holger `super.getBuffers()` is a List (as commented by the OP).

Comment: I know. So iterating twice is possible.

Comment: I have added a `reduce` based solution, which I like for its clarity, but there is no short-cutting `reduce` in the Stream API (I known, this has been requested by others before)…  I also added a `partitioningBy` solution which is the clean version of your second variant.

Comment: @Holger Your reduce based solution looks elegant. You already have my +1.

Answer (score 1):

You need a collection to reuse it.

You could use a `count()` instead of `collect(toList())` depending on whether you need the results.

```
List<ByteBuffer> list = super.getBuffers();
List<ByteBuffer> buffers = list.stream().filter(b -> b.position() > 0).collect(toList());
if (buffers.size() == list.size()) {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.FULLY_SENT;
} else if (buffers.isEmpty()) {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.WAS_NOT_SENT;
} else {
    return OutgoingMessageStatus.PARTIALLY_SENT;
}
```

Comment: So you’re collecting into a `List`, just to get the `count()`?

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying to solve the same question you had just with different type and predicate. Haven't found any satisfying answer so I implemented myself this way:

`Enum` to hold not just `true` and `false` for satisfying the predicate but also `NONE` (to be used for empty Collections) and `ENTANGLED` (to represent that some elements of collection satisfy the predicate and some do not):

```
public enum QuantumBoolean {
    NONE, TRUE, FALSE, ENTANGLED;

    public static QuantumBoolean fromBoolean(boolean bool) {
        if (bool) return QuantumBoolean.TRUE;
        return QuantumBoolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

To leverage the Java Stream API and to iterate over the collection just once I needed to call [`.reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) with specific arguments, so I packed them into new class:

```
public class QuantumBooleanReducer<T> {

    private final Predicate<T> predicate;
    public static final QuantumBoolean IDENTITY = QuantumBoolean.NONE;

    public QuantumBooleanReducer(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    public final QuantumBoolean accumulator(QuantumBoolean state, T element) {
        QuantumBoolean newState = QuantumBoolean.fromBoolean(predicate.test(element));
        if (QuantumBoolean.NONE.equals(state))
            return newState;
        if (newState.equals(state))
            return state;
        return QuantumBoolean.ENTANGLED;
    }

    public static QuantumBoolean combiner(QuantumBoolean state1, QuantumBoolean state2) {
        if (state1.equals(state2))
            return state1;
        if (QuantumBoolean.NONE.equals(state1))
            return state2;
        if (QuantumBoolean.NONE.equals(state2))
            return state1;
        return QuantumBoolean.ENTANGLED;
    }
}
```

Then you could solve your problem by calling something like:

```
switch(buffers.stream()
              .reduce(QuantumBooleanReducer.IDENTITY,
                      new QuantumBooleanReducer<ByteBuffer>(buffer -> buffer.position() > 0)::accumulator,
                      QuantumBooleanReducer::combiner)) {
            case FALSE:
                return OutgoingMessageStatus.WAS_NOT_SENT;
            case TRUE:
                return OutgoingMessageStatus.FULLY_SENT;
            case ENTANGLED:
                return OutgoingMessageStatus.PARTIALLY_SENT;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected Quantum Boolean");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't short-circuit

Comment: That is right but can really a task to tell if the collection either fully, partly or not at all fulfills the predicate short-circuit?
So you need a full one iteration cycle over the collection. Or am I not seeing something?