# Must partitioningBy produce a map with entries for true and false?

Tags: java, java-8, language-lawyer, java-stream

The [**partitioningBy**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) collector applies a predicate to each element in a stream and produces a map from booleans to lists of elements from the stream that satisfied or didn't satisfy the predicate.  For instance:

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4).collect(partitioningBy(x -> x >= 3))
// {false=[1, 2], true=[3, 4]}
```

As discussed in [What's the purpose of partitioningBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993604/whats-the-purpose-of-partitioningby), the *observed* behavior is that **partitioningBy** always returns a  map with entries for both **true** and **false**.  E.g.:

```
Stream.empty().collect(partitioningBy(x -> false));
// {false=[], true=[]}

Stream.of(1,2,3).collect(partitioningBy(x -> false));
// {false=[1, 2, 3], true=[]}

Stream.of(1,2,3).collect(partitioningBy(x -> true));
// {false=[], true=[1, 2, 3]}
```

Is that behavior actually specified somewhere? The Javadoc only says:

> Returns a Collector which partitions the input elements according to a
>   Predicate, and organizes them into a `Map<Boolean, List<T>>`. There are
>   no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or
>   thread-safety of the Map returned.

Could a conforming implementation return these instead:

```
Stream.empty().collect(partitioningBy(x -> false));
// {}, or {false=[]}, or {true=[]}

Stream.of(1,2,3).collect(partitioningBy(x -> false));
// {false=[1, 2, 3]}

Stream.of(1,2,3).collect(partitioningBy(x -> true));
// {true=[1, 2, 3]}
```

The corresponding [JSR 335](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335) only seems to include the same documentation, but not additional discussion about what entries the map will contain.

Comment: In Java 8, presence of both entries isn't specified, but in any implementation based on OpenJDK, both entries will always be present. Hypothetically a clean-room JDK implementation might have different behavior, but this seems unlikely to me. As user140547's answer noted, the Java 9 specification has been modified to require that both entries always be present.

Comment: @StuartMarks That was part of what motivated my question.  It seems like the quickest clean-room implementation based just on the Java 8 docs would be `partitioningBy(Predicate<T> predicate) { return groupingBy(predicate::test); }`, which wouldn't provide the empty lists in the results.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: True, but as there are only two possible and known keys (true and false), it would be annoying if you had to do a null check before iterating the lists...

Comment: @user140547 That's exactly the point.  The Java 8 docs don't provide the guarantee that both entries will be present, so (strictly speaking), you already have to do the null/containsKey checks.  That's why I wanted to know if there's a guarantee that both keys will have values.  The Java 9 docs provide that guarantee, so that the checks aren't necessary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In [Java 9 Javadoc of the method](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-), there is a clarification which makes it more explicit:

> The returned Map always contains mappings for both false and true keys.

Comment: Might be quiet fresh as we had [that discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036522/combine-allmatch-nonematch-and-anymatch-on-a-single-stream/41036977#comment69298278_41036977) only recently…

Comment: @Holger Yep, I popped in the spec change right after that, and the build with the change (b150) was posted just today.